# Fourier transform and Hodge-$*$ operator

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, elliptic-curves, hodge-theory

Suppose I have a full-rank lattice $\Lambda\subset\mathbf{C}$. Then the classical Poisson summation formula says
$$\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda}f(\lambda)=\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda'}\widehat{f}(\lambda)$$
where $\Lambda'$ is the dual lattice and $\widehat{f}$ is the Fourier transform. Depending on renormalizations of the Fourier transform, there's a volume factor on the right too.

> Is there any relation between the Poisson summation formula and the Hodge-$*$ operator on the $L^2$-completed smooth complex valued $1$-differentials on the Riemann surface $\mathbf{C}/\Lambda$?

Specifically, one has the heat kernel of the Laplacian $\Delta$ on the flat torus $\mathbf{C}/\Lambda$, with its own heat trace. Same for $\Delta*$, which gives two trace formulas, one for $e^{-t\Delta}$ and the other for $e^{-t\Delta*}$. These should be related by a "change of variable" and should give a formula such as the Poisson summation formula stated at the beginning. The  question really is: can one interpret the Poisson summation formula this way, with the Hodge-$*$ operator on $L^2$ one-forms having the effect of replacing functions with their Fourier transform in the trace formula?

I don't know how to make the question more precise, but hopefully I've explained what I have in mind enough for someone to perhaps see an answer.